# How does multiple inheritance work with super?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, method-resolution-order

Here are the few classes let's say, B, C, D and A, while in class A I am using super method which have class 'B' as an argument.

Where classes are as defined as below:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B')

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print('C')

class D:
    def __init__(self):
        print('D')


class A(B,C,D):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__()

A()
```

When I am trying to initiate the class A, it should invoke class B as I passed B in super method. But it is giving me output 'C'. If I am passing D in super instead of B it's not giving any output. Why? Instead it just invoke class A and leave.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The first argument to super tells it which implementation to _skip_ and start after. So given the MRO (A -> B -> C -> D -> object) `super(B, self).__init__()` calls the implementation in C. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super: _"The search starts from the class right after the type."_ In Python 3, use the no-args form unless there's a really good reason not to.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance

Comment: *All* the classes in the hierarchy need to use `super`, not just the child. `super` doesn't magically invoke multiple `__init__` methods; it just calls the *next* `__init__` method, which then has to use `super` itself to continue the chain of calls that will result in all the `__init__` methods being called in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

The class you pass as an argument to `super` should be the *current* class whose superclass we want to *look for*, not the target superclass. With your class `A`, the method resolution order is

```
A < B < C < D < object
```

So `super(A, self).__init__()` would call the method on the class *following* `A` in the MRO, which is `B`. Likewise, `super(B, self).__init__()` would call the one following `B`, which is `C`. `super(C, self)` would give us `D`, and `super(D, self)` would give us `object` (Side note: I don't know what `super(object, self)` does, but it seems to return a proxy object that just eats all method calls).

What you're looking for is

```
super(A, self).__init__()
```

but since you're inside a method and want to call the next method in the MRO chain anyway (the default, and most sane, behavior), you can use the 0-argument form.

```
super().__init__()
```

Comment: `super` is basically a type with special attribute lookup. The instance `super(A, self)` does little more than save a reference to `A` and `self`) (so that it can access `self.__mro__()`). When you ask for that instance's `__init__` attribute, you really get the `__init__` attribute of the first class in `self.__mro__()` following `A` that defines `__init__`.